# Chakra UI theme not rendering

Tags: reactjs, frontend, themes, styling, chakra-ui

I have followed the documentation of chakra UI and am trying to style my website. For some reason the config part for the dark/light mode works but the theme part does not work.

I have used create-react-app

This is my Index.js code-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { AuthProvider } from './Contexts/AuthProvider';
import { ChakraProvider, theme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import defaultTheme from "./Themes/stylesEntryPoint"
import { ColorModeScript } from '@chakra-ui/react'


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
    <ChakraProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <AuthProvider>
            <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
);
```

This is the code for stylesEntryPoint file

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import {theme,config} from "./FoundationTheme/globalStyles"

const defaultTheme = {
    theme , config
}


export default extendTheme(defaultTheme)
```

This is the code for globalStyles... I have copied it from chakra UI documentation here [https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/global-styles](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools'
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export const config = {
    initialColorMode: 'dark',
    useSystemColorMode: true
}

export const  theme = {
    styles: {
      global: (props) => ({
        'html, body': {
          fontSize: 'lg',
          color: props.colorMode === 'dark' ? 'pink.100' : 'gray.600',
          lineHeight: 'tall',
        },
        a: {
          color: props.colorMode === 'dark' ? 'teal.300' : 'teal.500',
        },
      }),
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`extendTheme` expects an object with the theme values that you want to override (`colors, fonts, styles, config, ...etc.`). Have a look at [chakra-ui theme](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/bea57af3fc039fce0d1b9ac272cdd65c21fd98e1/packages/components/theme/src/index.ts#L15) to understand what you're overwriting.

```
extendTheme({ 
  styles, 
  colors,
  fonts,
  config,
  …
})
```

### The problem

You're nesting those values inside another theme property inside defaultTheme like:

```
extendTheme({ theme, config })
```

### Solutions

Of course, you can spread theme object:

```
extendTheme({ ...theme, config })
```

Or you add config to the theme object in globalStyles:

```
export const theme = {
  styles: {
    global: (props) => {
      //…
    },
  },
  config
}

import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { defaultTheme } from "./FoundationTheme/globalStyles"

export default extendTheme(defaultTheme)
```

Or you do it like in the example from the documentation and import styles, colors etc. like you import config. You can even move config, styles, colors etc. in their own files. There is an example in the official documentation [how to structure the files](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#scaling-out-your-project).

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { config, styles } from "./FoundationTheme/globalStyles"

const defaultTheme = {
  styles,
  config,
}

export default extendTheme(defaultTheme)
```